# lost connectivity after changes made to rc.conf (freeBSD firewall)

Tags: linux, networking, dns, firewall, freebsd

I had a working configuration this morning with the following simple `/etc/rc.conf`
`/etc/resolv.conf` is completely commented out.

```
ifconfig_rl0="DHCP"
ifconfig_xl="inet 192.168.1.11 netmask 255.255.255."

defaultrouter="192.168.1.1"
```

I added the following lines:

```
firewall_enable="YES"
firewall_type="SIMPLE"
firewall_logging="YES"

sshd_enable="YES"
apache_enable="YES"
mysql_enable="YES"
```

restarted the computer and no connectivity, changed rc.conf back to last working configuration and still no connectivity.

```
ping www.google.com
#--> ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Host name lookup failure

ping 8.8.8.8 # --> (works fine)

apachectl start
#--> /usr/local/sbin/apachectl start: httpd could not be started

dig google.com
#--> connection timed out

nslookup google.com
#--> connnection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I also used `/etc/rc.d/routing restart` between the working state and the broken state

Comment: Try `dig google.com` and post the output. It sounds like a DNS problem.

Comment: Now how about output from `nslookup google.com`?

Comment: Wait... /etc/resolv.conf is empty? Or at least, it has no nameservers?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was working when empty this morning, but maybe not?

Comment: I doubt it. AFAIK, `/etc/resolv.conf` needs to be populated.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe on my router setup page there are two IPs for "static dns" and one for "local dns" which do you recommend? or should i use 8.8.8.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty. Try putting the following in it (to use Google's public DNS servers):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

That should work.

Comment: Try `apachectl status`. That sounds like a completely different problem, and may need its own question.

Comment: Probably would be a good idea. Especially the part about accepting my answer. :D

Comment: I'll post a new one, but here is (part of) the output `unable to connect to remote host.`

Comment: I'll take a look at your new question, there is a chance I will be able to answer it.

Comment: Why don't you put a link in a comment here so when I come back later I can look at the question?

Comment: here is the new question http://superuser.com/questions/662035/unable-to-start-apache-after-changes-to-rc-conf-and-resov-conf