# unable to start apache after changes to rc.conf and resov.conf

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, freebsd

I had a working configuration this morning with the following simple `/etc/rc.conf`

```
ifconfig_rl0="DHCP"
ifconfig_xl="inet 192.168.1.11 netmask 255.255.255."

defaultrouter="192.168.1.1"
```

I added the following lines:

```
firewall_enable="YES"
firewall_type="SIMPLE"
firewall_logging="YES"

sshd_enable="YES"
apache_enable="YES"
mysql_enable="YES"
```

my httpd.conf includes:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.11
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.11>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

now apache and ssh server are down. changed rc.conf back to last working configuration and still no ssh or apache

```
apachectl start
#--> /usr/local/sbin/apachectl start: httpd could not be started

apachectl status
#--> Looking up localhost
Making http connection to localhost
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.
```

Comment: What do the logs have to say?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg `mod_unique_id: unable to gethostbyname("")`

Comment: added `hostname="mydomain.com"` to `/etc/rc.conf` and now it apache works.  Still no ssh server.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noob questions.  I had to add the following to `/etc/rc.conf`

```
hostname="mydomain.com"
sshd_enable="YES"
apache_enable="YES"
```

A major source of confusion was my not rebooting after making changes to conf files.  I was restarting networking `/etc/rc.d/netif restart` but certain variables were still present.  (e.g. even though I restarted networking after deleting `hostname="mydomain.com` the hostname was still present"